# Eager loading nested, repeated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, eager-loading

Lets say I have a project model which has many members and many tasks.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :tasks
end
```

When a task is created in the project, we keep a record of which user created it. Only users who are a member of the current project can

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :project
end
```

In my `projects#show` action, I want to find a project and display it along with it's members, tasks and their creators. I try to eager load these things in order to speed up the query.

Since I am eager loading the searches members, and tasks can only have a creator who is a member, am I right in thinking that I don't have to include the task's creator specifically?

In other words, can I do this:

```
Search.includes(:members, :tasks)
```

or should I do this:

```
Search.includes(:members, :tasks => :creator)
```

Comment: I think you will need to explicitly include :creator otherwise it will query for it when you access the creator, because there is no way rails can know that creator is one of the already queried members.

Comment: @Abid It looks like you are correct. If you would like to move your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to explicitly include :creator otherwise it will query for it when you access the creator, because there is no way rails can know that creator is one of the already queried members